# Make another column linked to item with edit menu in sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: list, edit-form, edit

How can I change the column in a SharePoint list that has the link to the item and the link to the item with edit menu

Ex:
I currently have "Area" that is (linked to item with edit menu), but I want to delete that column and make ID linked to item with edit menu.

[image]

Comment: I know it is an old thread, but I think this change won't be populated if you create a new site based on the site with the change to the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using SharePoint Designer.

1. Open the site
2. Open the list
3. Edit "AllItems.aspx" or which view you want to modify
4. Look for `<ViewFields>`
5. Add the property `linkToItem="TRUE"`
   Note for SharePoint 2010 it is LinkToItem
   Example

Comment: Hi I am in sharepoint designer, and I don't see the Allitems.aspx file

Comment: The name might be different. You can check the available views. And then edit the one you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Open AllItems.aspx (or whatever your view page is) page in sharepoint designer. Now add `ListItemMenu="TRUE"` in `FieldRef` tag of your field where you want to add view and edit menu.