# How to make edit menu (ellipsis icon) be in another column?

Tags: list-view, contacts

I created a Contacts list and the ellipsis icon is badged to my `Last Name` column. It currently sits to the right of my `Last Name` column.

I want to either make the ellipsis icon column independent by itself, or make it appear to the left of my `Last Name` column instead.

I looked at the `.aspx` file in SharePoint Designer and in the `<ViewFields>` section, the element that is responsible for `Last Names` column is:

`<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>`

I've tried looking up previous threads like this one:

[Make another column linked to item with edit menu in sharepoint 2013 list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129255/make-another-column-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-in-sharepoint-2013-list)

But they don't appear to line up with my code. I was not able to find `linkToItem="TRUE"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to have the link and ellipsis to another column.  Yes, this can be achieved through SharePoint Designer. Right click All Items Under Views and **Edit File in Advanced Mode**

[image]

`<FieldRef Name="CellPhone" listItemMenu="TRUE" linkToItem="TRUE"/>`

Copy and Paste `listItemMenu="TRUE" linkToItem="TRUE"` to the desired `FieldRef` column.  Somehow `linkToItem` is case sensitive. I don't why but it didn't work for me if I change case.

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the path to get to this source code from SharePoint Designer? I don't believe I have access to it, which is why I am asking.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  you will need to edit the file in advanced mode. See the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. When I try to follow them and right click "All Items" under the "View" tab, I only have the option to "Rename", as there are no "Edit File in Advanced Mode" option. Here is my screenshot http://i.imgur.com/NHXmieJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Without editing the page itself, you could use an existing field or create a new blank field that you put in the first column of your view and then use the method posted below to add the ellipses to that field.

I've added JSLink code for adding the ellipsis menu to fields other than the Title field in a separate answer:

- [How to show ellipsis in a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94921/how-to-show-ellipsis-in-a-list/218270#218270)